# Where are the images my web browser downloads

Tags: php, javascript, html, http

Guys if we request a site on a server along with some images also those images are from the server.

Did we also request those images? I mean did those images got transfered to our hard disk?
because if not then the code in the site we request wont have images to refer, i mean those images are not saved on the browser the browser only has image name to refer to the original images.

If yes then were i can find these downloaded images from the server???

**EDIT, trying to make sense of the question**

When the browser requests a copy of a web page, does it also download the images needed as well?  How does it do this when it only has a file name.

If it does download the image, where does it save it on the hard drive?

Comment: without a request(say `GET`) to server from a browser or a client no data is transferred.. :)

Comment: please reconstruct your question first of all .. it's bit confusing!

Comment: what do you mean with request a copy. Are you just browsing the web. Or are you referring to saving with "save page as ..."

Comment: sorry im indian im bad at english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request a complete web page, the browser does download any images needed.

This images may, or may not, be saved on the local hard drive.  Many browsers have a `privacy mode` that means nothing gets written to disk.  In addition, the remote web server may ask the browser not to save them.

Under Internet Explorder, the images are in your Temporary Internet Files.  Google for that, since it changes location with versions of windows.

Under Firefox, they are stored in your `profile` directory.  Again, the location of that directory changes as well.

The file names seldom, if ever, have anything to do with the image name given in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When you reach a webpage it's images are donwloaded to your computer internet temporary files, so your browser is able to render it, they also are stored on temporary files to cache them, so the next time you hit the webpage you haven't to re download them and can render the whole page faster.

Keep in mind that using images from an external site could be illegal or conduce to rights infringment.

Comment: It's special space in memory where data is stored for quick access.

Comment: Nope, cookies are browser specific data stores.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you visit a webpage and that webpage includes images, then those images are downloaded to your hard-drive so they can be displayed in the browser.

I won't say “Google it”, but in this case, just [a little bit of research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) would go a long way.